# Talking to bitcoind thru web browser returns empty JSON document

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I am attempting to access bitcoind's http-json-rpc api thru firefox. I enter the following URL

```
http://user:password@localhost:8332/getinfo
```

and it returns

```
There was an error parsing the JSON document. The document may not be well-formed.
Document contents:
```

So the document contents are empty, but when I inspect element and look at the response, I get

```
Status-code: 404 Not Found
Connection: Close
Content-Type: "application/json"
Server: "bitcoin-json-rpc/v0.8.2-815-g5f083af-beta"
```

So the server is replying, but doesn't recognize the request or something.

My bitcoin.conf file reads

```
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
rpcport=8332
```

If I do

```
 http://user:password@localhost:8332/
```

instead, it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error

Any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to POST the request according to the [JSON RPC specifications](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification). So this will not work using Firefox without any special extension that lets you set POST information. You cannot simply request the page `http://user:password@localhost:8332/getinfo` and expect `bitcoind` to return the `getinfo`. There is no page system, it's not a normal www-server (i.e. pages hyperlinked together), it just uses the HTTP protocol to transport JSON. As long as you make that POST request correctly, I don't think it mattes what page you call.